# Marshaller on Windows adds new line at the end of file

Tags: java, xml, windows, unix, jaxb

I have a project that uses JAXB marshalled XML files in order to compare configuration states of different environments. I noticed that there must be some differences in the implementation of the JAXB marshaller under Windows against the Unix version. When I compare 2 files created on the different platforms, my comparison tool always flags one difference at the end of the file. The file created on Windows has a new line (CR and LF) at the end of the file while the Unix version doesn't have it.

Please note that the issue is **not about the difference of the new line characters between both platforms**! The Windows marshaller effectively adds a "new line" at the end of the file while the Unix marshaller stops after the closing ">" of the root tag.

[image: Windows marshaller adds a new line at the end]

Is there any parameter I can pass to the marshaller in order to prevent this additional line or do I have to explicitly remove it after marshalling on Windows, so that my comparison tool doesn't flag the difference?

This is how the marshalling code looks like:

```
  public void marshal(final Object rootObject, final OutputStream outputStream) throws JAXBException, TransformerException {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(rootObject != null, "rootObject must not be null");
    Preconditions.checkArgument(outputStream != null, "outputStream must not be null");
    final JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(rootObject.getClass());
    final Document document = getFactories().newDocument();
    document.setXmlStandalone(true);
    final Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setSchema(schema);
    marshaller.marshal(rootObject, document);
    createTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(outputStream));
  }

  public static Transformer createTransformer() {
    final Transformer transformer = getFactories().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, JAXBDefaults.OUTPUT_CHARSET.name());
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, CDATA_XML_ELEMENTS);
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", IDENT_LENGTH);
    return transformer;
  }


  private static class JAXBFactories {

    private DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory;

    public DocumentBuilderFactory getDocumentBuilderFactory() {
      if (documentBuilderFactory == null) {
        documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      }
      return documentBuilderFactory;
    }

    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    public DocumentBuilder getDocumentBuilder() {
      if (documentBuilder == null) {
        try {
          documentBuilder = getDocumentBuilderFactory().newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (final ParserConfigurationException ex) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create DocumentBuilder", ex);
        }
      }
      return documentBuilder;
    }

    public Document newDocument() {
      return getDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    }

    private TransformerFactory transformerFactory;

    public TransformerFactory getTransformerFactory() {
      if (transformerFactory == null) {
        transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      }
      return transformerFactory;
    }

    public Transformer newTransformer() {
      try {
        return getTransformerFactory().newTransformer();
      } catch (final TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create Transformer", ex);
      }
    }

  }

  private static class FactoriesHolder {

    static final JAXBFactories FACTORIES = new JAXBFactories();
  }

  private static JAXBFactories getFactories() {
    return FactoriesHolder.FACTORIES;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason (or expectation) that pretty-printing XML will produce exactly the same results from two different systems. It does, however, seem likely that if you switched off the pretty printing (and let yourt IDE/editor do that) you are likely to discover that the output is the same.

Pretty-printing XML is a transform of the original that adds layout. It is no longer *real* xml.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I fully get your point.However, my problem is that one of the main reasons why I had chosen XML was the human readability it offers and the possibility to compare easily with any comparison tool. Now because of this extra line, I get a lot of false differences when comparing multiple files at once.

You don't happen to know a good tool for XML comparison, do you? :)
Plain text comparison worked OK for now but there are many other issues apart from that new line issue.

Comment: @Alex - [KDiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) can be told to ignore white-space while comparing. This does not solve all problems but it helps a great deal.